# Getting unexpected results from SQL query

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables. 1 called "recipes" and one called "ingredients". In the recipes table I have: id, recipe_name, calories, bld (an enumerated list that can be B, L, or D for breakfast, lunch and dinner), prep (prep time), and skill (another enumerated list for beg, int, and adv).

In the ingredients table I have: recipe_id (with a foreign key constraint to the id column in the recipes table), and ingredient_name, and some other columns.

Im trying to select all of the columns from the recipes table and the ingredient_name comlumn from the ingredients table with some conditions - I want to return all recipes, even if they dont have ingredients in the ingredient table (this wouldnt really happen in practice but this is for me to learn anyway), and I want to exclude recipes if one of their ingredients includes part of a keyword the user enters (in the next example ill be using "olive" as the keyword).

Here's my SQL so far:

```
SELECT recipes.*, ingredients.ingredient_name
FROM recipes
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredients
ON ingredients.recipe_id=recipes.id
WHERE ingredients.ingredient_name <> '%olive%'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7
```

This only returns the recipes with ingredients and is still including recipes where "olive" is part of one of the names of the ingredients.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You aren't answering your question properly.  All you are doing is removing any records from ingredients that contain '%olive%' in them.  You are ~not~ limiting to only recipes that have that ingredient line.  As an aside, the "recipes.*" is bad practice.  Even though you have to type a bit more, a complete column list you wish is a better convention.

Answer (score 1):

It's best, when working with this type of logic, to think in sets of data.

**Set 1**: List of recipes where Olive is in the ingredients:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM ingredients
WHERE ingredient_name LIKE '%olive%'
```

Now we have a set of recipes that we can exclude because they have Olive in them.

**SET 2**: List of recipes and their ingredients:

```
SELECT recipes.*, ingredients.ingredient_name
FROM recipes
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredients
ON ingredients.recipe_id=recipes.id
```

No surprises here. Just a set of everything. What we want to do is restrict this set, by the set in the previous step:

**SET 3**: Restrict SET2 set with SET1 set:

```
SELECT recipes.*, ingredients.ingredient_name
FROM recipes
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredients
ON ingredients.recipe_id=recipes.id
WHERE recipes.id NOT IN 
   (
     SELECT recipe_id
     FROM ingredients
     WHERE ingredient_name LIKE '%olive%'
   )
```

Comment: Good answer. Alternatively - _WHERE recipes.id NOT IN_ could be replaced with _WHERE  NOT EXISTS_ in "SET 3"

Comment: Thanks a lot! Going to test this now